# Is $x^2\geq 0$ an axiom?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

For real numbers, $x^2\geq 0$ is always true, but why actually?

Is it an axiom, definition or is there a proof?

Comment: It is a theorem that trivially follows from the definition/axiom of the multiplication of signed numbers. The latter waschosen in such a way that signed numbers form a group for multiplication.

Comment: $x^2 \geq 0$ is not always true. For example in $\mathbb{C}$ we have $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @JDoeDoe : can you write down the definition of your symbol $\geq$ .

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Updated. For real numbers.

Comment: From Rudin: $x^2 \geq 0$ holds for any ordered field. For a proof, apply the definition of an ordered field to $x$ with separate cases

Answer (score 5):

Any of the above, depending on exposition.

---

There are two typical axiomatic approaches to ordered fields, which boil down to how to relate multiplication to the ordering.

One version axiomatizes the ordering, and including the requirement that if $0 \leq a$ and $0 \leq b$, then $0 \leq a \cdot b$.

One can then use this, along with trichotemy, to show that $0 \leq x^2$. (using the fact $x^2 = (-x)^2$)

In the other version, one axiomatizes the positive numbers, including the requirement that $x^2$ is positive for every nonzero $x$.

Comment: $(-x)^2=$ $0+(-x)^2=$ $ x\cdot 0+(-x)^2=$ $x\cdot (x+(-x))+(-x)^2=$ $(x^2+x(-x))+(-x)^2=$ $=x^2+(x(-x)+(-x)^2)=$ $x^2+(x+(-x))(-x)=$ $x^2+0\cdot (-x)=$ $x^2+0=$ $x^2.$.....In case anyone asks you in a comment whether $x^2=(-x)^2$ is an axiom.